# ReLU when outputs should be constrained

Tags: neural-networks

I'm working on a neural network, and I was wondering whether, when I want to constrain the output to be in the range (0,1), I should still be using ReLU (assuming I still want the advantages ReLU has in training). Would it eventually learn on its own to ensure that the weights arrive at this result, or would using a function that's already defined as having an output of (0,1) such as the sigmoid function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your neural network will learn to stay in the range of `(0,1)` after a while. But the best thing to do is to keep the sigmoid function on just the output layer, and the ReLU on the rest of the layers. That way you will never have an output that is out of bound.